# C++ concepts for numeric types and preventing instantiation on pointers

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I'm trying to write a concept that instantiates a function if the template parameter is only of numeric type (integers, floats, doubles and so on) and throw an error if the type is a pointer type or a boolean type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>

template<typename T>
concept NumericType = requires(T param)
{
    {std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>};
    {!std::is_same_v<bool, T>};
    {std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(param +1)>};
    !std::is_pointer_v<T>;
};
```

But when I try to use it with pointer to int or float or double, the compiler instantiates the function and adds one to the pointer which works because of pointer arithmetic.

```
template<NumericType T>
T add_one(const T val)
{
    return val + 1;
}

int main(){
    int two{2};
    int* pTwo = &two;
    float three{3.1415};


    std::cout << "add_one(two):  " << add_one(two) << "\n";
    std::cout << "add_one(&two): " << add_one(&two) << "\n";
    std::cout << "add_one(pTwo): " << add_one(pTwo) << "\n";
    std::cout << "add_one(&three): " << add_one(&three) << "\n";
    std::cout << "add_one(true):  " << add_one(true) << "\n";

    return 0;

}
```

I was expecting the compiler to throw error for the cases where pointer or boolean types passed to `add_one` function, but surprisingly it doesn't

I fail to understand what what is wrong with the definition of concept `NumericType` since it contains a clause within the body of the concept definition that hints the compiler that type `T` should not be of pointer or boolean type using the type trait `std::pointer_v<T>` `!std::is_same_v<T, bool>. Here's a [working example](https://godbolt.org/z/aWEaT5sh9) on compiler explorer.

Comment: Tl;DR - you check the expressions are well-formed, not that that their value is true. Common pitfall, it would seem. Besides that... your concept may be better written as a conjunction rather than individual nested requirements. It will play better with constraint subsumption.

Comment: As you're already using `is_arithmetic`, afaik its actually defined as `std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>`, so you could replace the first line. Also, somebody told me it's better to define concepts with other concepts, instead of type traits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `requires` clause only checks the *validity* of the expression and does not evaluate the value, you need to use nested `requires`:

```
template<typename T>
concept NumericType = requires(T param)
{
    requires std::is_integral_v<T> || std::is_floating_point_v<T>;
    requires !std::is_same_v<bool, T>;
    requires std::is_arithmetic_v<decltype(param +1)>;
    requires !std::is_pointer_v<T>;
};
```